# How to make the menubar work like a proper menubar without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you a menubar work **properly** menubar with the functions:
*Clicking on hamburger-icon will display the nav-links.
*Clicking on nav-links will hide the menubar.

(**without using bootstrap, but doing it from scratch**)

I understand that many have asked this question. I have looked at many different solutions, with JS and Jquery, and I have encountered several problems because I really dont understand JS or Jquery fully.

*This is how far I´ve gotten.* Go to my website **hung.no** so you can see the problem. On my website, you should minimize the window to get to the hamburger bar. Then you should click on that bar. After that click on one of the nav-links. **It closes, but** when you try to click on the hamburger bar again, **it does not work**.

```js
//Navbar collapses to menubar
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}



//Jquery code ON MY WEBSITE. I cannot display it here.
//This is the source
//<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $(".nav-link").click(function(){
//        $(".nav-toggle").hide();
//    });
//});
//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $(".nav-show").click(function(){
//        $(".nav-toggle").show();
//    });
//});
```

```css
/*mobile navbar*/


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}


.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
    

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
    #myNavbar{
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none!important;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
    .mob-font-size{
        font-size: 22px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mob-logo-size{
     width: 177px;
    height: 260px;
    }
}
    

/*dekstop navbar*/

#myNavbar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.float-right-nav{
    padding: 8px 15px;
    float: right;
}


#myNavbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


div.container
{
  margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 6px 3em;
 text-align: center;
}

div.container a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Raleway-medium;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--desktop navbar-->
<div id="myNavbar">
    <div class="container">
<ul>
  <li style="float:left"><a href="#home"><img  src="svg/navlogo.svg" alt=""></a></li>
   <li class="float-right-nav"><a href="#Kontakt"><span class="medium">KONTAKT</span></a></li> 
   <li class="float-right-nav"><a href="#Pris"><span class="medium">PRIS</span></a></li>
     <li class="float-right-nav"><a href="#Garantier"><span class="medium">GARANTIER</span></a></li>
  <li class="float-right-nav"><a href="#Ommeg"><span class="medium">OM MEG</span></a></li>
</ul>
     </div>
</div>


<!--Mobile navbar the classes nav-link and nav-toggle is used in the Jquery code located in the Javascript-section in this Code Snippet-->

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a style="float:left" href="#home"><img  src="svg/navlogo.svg" alt="" height="20" width="18"></a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-toggle"href="#Kontakt"><span class="medium">KONTAKT</span></a>
   <a class="nav-link nav-toggle"href="#Pris"><span class="medium">PRIS</span></a>
     <a class="nav-link nav-toggle"href="#Garantier"><span class="medium">GARANTIER</span></a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-toggle"href="#Ommeg"><span class="medium">OM MEG</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in your javascript function "myFunction"

When you click a first time, you append class "resposive", but when you click again the flow moves to "else"  and then it remove "responsive" so you are removing that behaviour.

If you remove that flow then the nav works fine.

Comment: I don´t understand. This is the first time I using JS. Could you please show  me? And have you looked at my website?:)

Comment: You need remove de "else" condition: function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    }